# Footer requires scrolling to be fully visible

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Building a new website using Wordpress 4.2.3 with Tesseract 1.0 theme, ran into a problem that only 1/3 of the Footer is visible immediately, seeing the rest requires scrolling down.

This happens even on a page that is almost empty and the browser window maximised, screen resolution 1920x1080.

Same problem with Firefox and Chrome. I would expect to see the whole footer without any scrolling.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two routes I would go:

1) Check the jQuery script running on page load may be finding .height() of your footer instead of .outerHeight()?; the later would calculate height including padding and margin. The former would not.

2) Without tinkering with the script, take off the 40px top/bottom padding on your footer and instead use a wrapper element inside your footer for placing the content. Give the padding to that wrapper instead. This should alleviate any issues with calculating sizes of elements in your script.

Comment: thank you sir, that sounds like a really good answer! will give it a try in the next session.